# How to generate allure-results in root module in multi-module gradle application?

Tags: java, gradle, allure

So I have multiple submodules containing tests that I want to be uploaded to Allure. Each of the modules have following dependencies from the root module

```
'io.qameta.allure:allure-junit5-assert'
'io.qameta.allure:allure-rest-assured'
```

But when I run the tests the `allure-results` directory is created independently for each module inside its build directory.
Is it possible to make allure create one `allure-results` directory in the root module which will contain the results of the tests from all submodules?

I tried to add `allure.properties` file to the resources of each module
with following line:

```
allure.results.directory=<absolute path to the root module>/build/allure-results
```

and it seems to work. But I wonder is there a more reasonable solution that does not involve duplicating code in different modules?

Answer (score -1):

I can’t see a test that checks whether ENV is null. Further, it’s not obvious whether ServerEnv.ENV_PROPERTY is "ENVIRONMENT". If they are supposed to be the same, why not use the same form consistently? Regarding the initialization time, this document says “A companion object is initialized when the corresponding class is loaded (resolved) that matches the semantics of a Java static initializer” but there is no use of the class at all in your posted code.

Comment: This should be a comment.